# javascript function validate not working

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/just4upvp/Gt8TY/1/

I'm new to javascript and I'm not able to find error in my code, validateForm was working and now it is not working.  Please help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        if (document.enrollment.cfname.value == "") {
          errcfname.innerHTML = "Please enter firstname";
          return false;
          }
    }
    function validate(id,error) {
        var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
        var err = document.getElementById(error);
        if(!value) {
            err.innerHTML = "*required";
        } else {
            err.innerHTML = "*";
        }
    }
</script>





<form  name="enrollment" method="post" action="confirmation.php"   
       enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return (validateForm());"> 
<label for="cfname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="cfname" name="cfname" size="20" maxlength="15" 
       autofocus="autofocus" required="required"
       onblur="validate(this.id,'errcfname')"/>
<span class="error1" id="errcfname">*</span>
```

Comment: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_debugging_for_beginners/

Comment: onblur works but validateForm is not working

Comment: @Sergio yes the fiddle works but it is not working on my web page.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions return `undefined` if no return value is defined. 
EDIT: For your second problem, getElementById is much more reliable when manipulating DOM.

Change your validateForm() function like -

```
function validateForm() {
    if (document.getElementById('cfname').value === '') {
      document.getElementById('errcfname').innerHTML = "Please enter firstname";
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Reference - http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html

> JavaScript does not have a void type, so every function must return a value. The default value is undefined, except for constructors, where the default return value is this.

Comment: changed it but still have problem.

Comment: on submit if firstname is empty it should show 'please enter firtname'. but it is not working.

Comment: ok, I don't know why but when I removed required="required" from other form controls it is working.